# EJS Reference Error trying to pass key value pairs using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm having a weird issue with EJS when I use res.render to try and pass the javascript object (key:value).

For example, this works just fine (having two separate app.get requests work's great):

```
///////////root route
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Featuredblog.find({}, function (err, blogs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("home", { blogs: blogs });
    }
  });
});

////////GET FEATURED VIDEO PAGE SECTION
app.get("/featuredvideo", function (req, res) {
  Featuredpost.find({}, function (err, videos) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("featuredvideo", { videos: videos });
    }
  });
});
```

But I don't want the Featured Videos to be on a separate page. I want them to be on the home page along with the featured blog posts.

But when I go to combine them into the app.get("/") request, it gives EJS Reference Error saying "videos" is not defined at eval (eval at compile...

Here is what it looks like when I combine them:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Featuredblog.find({}, function (err, blogs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("home", { blogs: blogs });
    }
  });

  Featuredpost.find({}, function (err, videos) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("home", { videos: videos });
    }
  });
});
```

It has no problem with passing "blogs"key value, it's only the "videos" key that gives me trouble. Also, when I console.log("Success") after for the else statement, it logs "Success", so the function works.

Both my home.ejs and featuredvideos.ejs files are in my "views" folder.

Here is what my home.ejs file looks like:

```
<!-- featured blog section -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1 class="video-title">Featured Blogs</h1>

    <% blogs.forEach(function(blog) { %>

  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="video">
      <div class="blog-image">
        <img src="/images/<%= blog.image %>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video video-text">
      <h1> <%= blog.title %> </h1>
      <p>
        <%= blog.content.substring(0, 700) %> ... <mark>Read More.</mark>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%  }); %>
</div>


<!-- featured Videos section -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1 class="video-title">Featured Videos</h1>

    <% videos.forEach(function(video) { %>

  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="video">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<%= video.video %>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video video-text">
      <h1> <%= video.title %> </h1>
      <p>
        <%= video.content.substring(0, 700) %>  ... <mark>Read More.</mark>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%  }); %>
</div>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ReferenceError: /Users/Louieg3/Documents/WEB DEVELOPMENT/mindunravelledexpress/views/home.ejs:47
    45| 
    46| 
 >> 47|     <% videos.forEach(function(video) { %>
    48| 
    49|   <div class="video-container">
    50|     <div class="video">

videos is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/Louieg3/Documents/WEB DEVELOPMENT/mindunravelledexpress/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:649:12), <anonymous>:26:8)
    at home (/Users/Louieg3/Documents/WEB DEVELOPMENT/mindunravelledexpress/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:679:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/Louieg3/Documents/WEB DEVELOPMENT/mindunravelledexpress/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/Louieg3/Documents/WEB DEVELOPMENT/mindunravelledexpress/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:478:10)
    at View.render (/Users/Louieg3/Documents/WEB DEVELOPMENT/mindunravelledexpress/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/Louieg3/Documents/WEB ... etc.
```

Any thoughts? I'm not sure why it would work when it's broken out into a separate app.get request, vs being part of the root route get request. I can't see anything online about having two separate functions giving a problem with EJS and Node.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It seems like you're running *both* `res.render("home", { blogs: blogs })` **and**  `res.render("home", { videos: videos })` with every request to `/`. Since your home template expects both `blogs` and `videos`, at least one of those is missing on each call to `res.render`. (Furthermore, I don't know EJS, but I suspect calling `res.render` twice on a single response is never a valid thing to do.) Did you simply mean to make a single call like `res.render("home", { blogs: blogs, videos: videos })`?

Comment: calling render method twice does not do any good. Only first render method is being called. you will have to get both blogs and videos from database and call render once with both of them like `res.render('index', {blogs: blogs, videos: videos})`

Comment: That makes sense that when it can only use one res.render, but how would I be able to combine them? I don't see how since I'm calling the mode.find() method from two separate collections. Or how to do I pass the return from two separate find()'s into the same res.render call? And they need to stay in two separate sections under the same home page (one collection goes under h1 title 'Featured Blogs' and the other under the h1 title 'Featured Videos').

Comment: @Louieg3 Are you just looking for a solution to nest the `find` calls one inside the other, like `Featuredblog.find({}, function (err, blogs) { Featuredpost.find({}, function (err, videos) { res.render(....) }) });`?

Comment: I was trying to nest them the wrong way all along. Because it wasn't working I thought you couldn't nest them. But because you had mentioned nesting them would work, I gave it another shot.

Comment: Here is the method I used to get it to work. Thank you for your help!                                 app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Featuredblog.find({}, function (err, blogs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      Featuredvid.find({}, function (err, videos) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.render("home", { videos: videos, blogs: blogs });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});